# Are achievements tracked across playthroughs?

Tags: achievements, magicka

Having recently completed Magicka's adventure (enjoying myself quite a bit in the process), I was delighted to see that you can start the game again with all the magicks you unlocked still available.

Seeing how I didn't manage to track down all magicks on my first playthrough, I was wondering if collecting only the ones I missed on this additional playthrough would net me the "I put on my wizard robe and hat" achievement.

That, in turn, got me wondering whether other achievements are tracked across playthroughs. For example, I managed to rack up around 650 overkills. Will I only need 350 more on my second run to get the corresponding achievement, or will I need to collect the full 1000?

You get the gist of things. Which achievements, if any, are tracked across multiple playthroughs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe most, if not all, of the accumulative achievements are tracked across multiple playthroughs. Like the moose finding achievement, I know I have been using several playthroughs trying to get that and so far it has tracked my progress accross all of them.

Comment: I forgot I asked this. Seeing how I ended up testing this myself, I can definitely corroborate your answer.